# How do you fix? formtastic :label_method is no longer available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, combobox, formtastic, label

Ok.. I'm new to ruby/rails. So to compensate for my weakness, my company had a guy come in to help me create the bones of our website. He put in formtastic :label_method, so we could change what fields are displayed in the DDLB. 
When I moved my project to a new box, I got this error.

:label_method is no longer available

What I'm wondering is.. what do I use in it's place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it might be:

```
:member_label
```

According to http://rubydoc.info/gems/formtastic/2.0.0/Formtastic/Helpers/InputHelper

"(Symbol, Proc, Method) — Deprecated, renamed to :member_label"

If that doesn't work could you post your _form for us to see?

Comment: actually I was just trying to answer my own question with the same text.. Thanks. I was also going to vent a bit about how three hours on something like this makes me just love Ruby.  How now I have to edit 30 forms with this lovely gotcha. How I miss the unchanging C

Comment: Awesome! Sometimes just typing the question out makes me realize the answer. Good luck with Rails!

Comment: Just for the record:  someone changing a library written in ruby does not make ruby anymore changeable than C.  C libraries change as well.  If you don't like the changes, you can always use older versions of the C libraries, in exactly the same way that you could choose to use an older version of formtastic that would not require you to change a single line of code...

Comment: @XacaXulu I think you mis-typed this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`:member_label` is the thing to use!

**EDIT:**
More recently, I could not get both of these (including `:label_method`) to work. The way I used was to define a `to_label` method on the model.